# Binding EventToCommand in Code for localized ApplicationBar

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

How can I bind EventToCommand programmatically to an ApplicationBar Button or MenuItem in Windows Phone 8? I'm currently using MVVM light and it works perfectly for all elements I can add in XAML.

Normally, I would define the ApplicationBar from Xaml and could bind from there EventToCommand in Expression Blend. But starting with WP8, Microsoft deciced to prefer an [localizable ApplicationBar which will be created programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_LocalizinganApplicationBar), as it cannot be bind that easily to different languages.

What is necessary to reproduce the same behaviour as if I would push a Button to execute EventToCommand? Is this even possible or encouraged regarding the MVVM pattern? What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same old WP7 AppBar in WP8. LocalizableAppBar is just a recommendation on how to localize the AppBar.

Either way, you're likely weren't using EventToCommand on the AppBar since it doesn't support DataBinding. You'll need to use a Bindable AppBar for that. Either write a homegrown one or use one of the many OSS solutions for that, such as: [AppBarUtils](http://nuget.org/packages/AppBarUtils),  [BindableApplicationBar](http://nuget.org/packages/BindableApplicationBar), [Cimbalino](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/cimbalino-windows-phone-4de77988) or others.

Localizing one of the aforementioned ApBars will be a lot simpler since you can then databind the text to the ViewModel and use whatever text you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cimbalino looks promising, I'll will give this a try. Then I guess my main problem is a localizable AppBar with support for EventToCommand, or Binding in general. But can I use these bindable AppBars easily from Blend or do I need to assign EventToCommand programmatically (which brings me back to my first question :)

Comment: You can use bindable AppBars from Blend AND they should work fine with EventToCommand. They might be a bit wonky on the blend design surface, but they'll work fine. Most of the Bindable AppBars might even expose a Command property which you can use directly instead of using EventToCommand.

Comment: Your suggestion was awesome! Cimbalino worked immediately out of the box. I could add language support and could use my defined commands, thank you!